# I use sass with my components and storybook doesnt recognise the scss style sheets. How to configure scss file support

Tags: reactjs, sass, storybook

I use storybook 7.0.24 with my react application with typescript. My component folder is setup in the following structure.

MYComponent
-> index.tsx
-> _style.scss

When I add the stories to include my component it doesnt load / recognise my style sheet and breaks the components styling.

Below is the main.ts in .storybook folder

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  staticDirs: ["..\\public"],
};
export default config;
```

Can someone kindly guide me on how to configure storybook to recognise and read my _style.scss file

Comment: Maybe you need to set up the [sass addon](https://storybook.js.org/recipes/sass) or [sass postcss addon](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-sass-postcss/)?